# Run framework 4.0 application without installing on client machine

Tags: dll, frameworks, .net-4.0

is there a way to run a windows application in the client machine without installing the .NET framework 4.0?
I try to set the "Copy local" to true on all dll's but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: If it is compiled against the 4.0 framework then the framework must be installed on the client there is no way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET 4.0 is actually a new version of the CLR, so there isn't binary compatibility between assemblies compiles with 4.0 vs. 3.5 and 2.0.

In the case of 3.5, you could just copy local because it was the same CLR as 2.0...but alas, not with 4.0.